# Graphics and negative ordinate

Tags: java, swing, graphics, coordinates

I want to display points that can have negative coordinates (X and Y). For now, points that have a negative X seem to be correctly displayed (ie. : they are at the left of the points that have positive X).

However, points that have negative Y are displayed at the top of my graph : as an exemple, a point with Y = -5 will be displayed in top of a point with Y = -3...

How can I reverse this `Graphics`' displaying ?

My (simple) code :

```
package general_classes;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Graph extends JFrame {

    private List<StorableData> list_detected_points;
    private List<StorableData> list_all_points;
    private Cupple barycenter;

    public Graph(String title, List<StorableData> list_all_points, List<StorableData> list_detected_points) {

        double scaling_coef = 200;
        double move_x = 500, move_y = 500;


        this.add(new JPanel() {
            private Graphics graphics;

            int x, y;
            private void drawPoint(Cupple storable_data) {
                x = (int) (storable_data.getNumber(0) * scaling_coef + move_x);
                y = (int) (storable_data.getNumber(1) * scaling_coef + move_y);
                graphics.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                graphics.drawString(storable_data.toString(), x - 5, y - 5);
            }

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                this.graphics = graphics;

                for(StorableData storable_data : list_all_points) {
                    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    this.drawPoint((Cupple) storable_data);
                }

                if(list_detected_points != null) {
                    for (StorableData storable_data : list_detected_points) {
                        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
                        this.drawPoint((Cupple) storable_data);

                    }
                }

            }
        });

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you want to print the point with a negative coordinate?

Comment: In the same graph, and A(... ; -Y) must be displayed at bottom of B ( ... ; -Y+1)

Comment: Most graphics systems (like Java2D) has the origin (0,0) in the upper left corner, with positive x right and positive y *down*. This is an historical thing, as most computer display hardware actually draws this way. So what you experience, is just as it should be. See `AffineTransform` or `Graphics2D.translate(...)` for how to change the logical origin.

Comment: The `AffineTransform` is your friend here..,

Comment: PS: Note that you should usually *not* have a `Graphics` object as an instance variable in a `Compoent` subclass, instead pass on the instance you get in the `paint(Graphics)` callback. For `JComponent`s it's usually also better to override `paintComponent` than `paint`.

Comment: I don't know how I should use `AffineTransform` : I understand it can "reverse" my ordinates, but it takes a `double[]` parameter.

Comment: Here is an example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

Comment: Okay, thank you guys, I'm using `AffineTransform`. So I deleted my ` * scaling_coef + move_[x|y]` , thinking that `AffineTransform :: scale` would do a good scaling with my points. However it's not the case. Should I keep my previously shown operation, and just use `AffineTransform` to reverse points according their ordinate ? Edit : btw, I used `invert`and other invert-like functions, none inverted my points (according - or not - to Y)

Comment: Look at the answer I added to your question. You need to configure the AffineTransform properly first.

Comment: Well, I got the min coordinates (X and Y) and I used `AffineTransform` to scale : `affine_transform.translate(getWidth()/(x_max - x_min    ), getHeight()/(y_max - y_min));` (`getWidth/getHeight` are the graph's dimensions more or less). Now, the points are all shown in the same place (so they are all overlaped). That's a bigger problem :( - Code (few lines) : https://pastebin.com/3rP6Y8ix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AffineTransform with very little coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293980/how-to-use-affinetransform-with-very-little-coordinates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you receive all the points you need to draw, first find the minimum and the maximum coordinates on each dimension. With this, you can obtain an scaling factor (using the distance between min and max, and the size of the drawing box you have) and an offset (so that the min will correspond to the zero of your draw box).

Then create an `AffineTransform` with the data above that it will correctly convert each point when you are drawing it.

Comment: I did it, but all my points are displayed exactly on the same place. You can see the 5 lines here : https://pastebin.com/3rP6Y8ix

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots of the result, better to post the changed (compilable, runnable) code as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: As an aside, it appears this task requires two instances of `AffineTransform`. The first would *scale* the range of values to (almost) fill the available space (leave some small border around the edges of the points). The second would shift (translate) the co-ordinates so that they are all positive (& therefore visible on the panel).