# How to use AffineTransform with very little coordinates?

Tags: java, coordinates, graphics2d, affinetransform

I have a set of two dimensions points. Their X and Y are greater than -2 and lesser than 2. Such point could be : `(-0.00012 ; 1.2334 )`.

I would want to display these points on a graph, using rectangles (a rectangle illustrates a point, and has its coordinates set to its point's ones - moreover, it has a size of 10*10).

Rectangles like (... ; Y) should be displayed *above* any rectangles like (... ; Y-1) (positive Y direction is up). Thus, I must set the graph's origin not at the top-left hand-corner, but somewhere else.

I'm trying to use `Graphics2D`'s `AffineTransform` to do that.

1. I get the minimal value for all the X coordinates
2. I get the minimal value for all the Y coordinates
3. I get the maximal value for all the X coordinates
4. I get the maximal value for all the Y coordinates
5. I get the distance `xmax-xmin` and `ymax-ymin`
6. Then, I wrote the code I give you below.

---

**Screenshots**

Some days ago, using my own method to scale, I had this graph:
[image]
(so as I explained, Y are inverted and that's not a good thing)

For the moment, i.e., with the code I give you below, I have only one point that takes *all* the graph's place! Not good at all.

I would want to have:
[image]
(without lines, and without graph's axis. The important here is that points are correctly displayed, according to their coordinates).

---

**Code**

To get min and max coordinates value:

```
x_min = Double.parseDouble((String) list_all_points.get(0).get(0));
x_max = Double.parseDouble((String) list_all_points.get(0).get(0));
y_min = Double.parseDouble((String) list_all_points.get(0).get(1));
y_max = Double.parseDouble((String) list_all_points.get(0).get(1));
for(StorableData s : list_all_points) {
    if(Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(0)) < x_min) {
        x_min = Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(0));
    }
    if(Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(0)) > x_max) {
        x_max = Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(0));
    }

    if(Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(1)) < y_min) {
        y_min = Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(1));
    }
    if(Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(1)) > y_max) {
        y_max = Double.parseDouble((String) s.get(1));
    }
}
```

To draw a point:

```
int x, y;
private void drawPoint(Cupple storable_data) {
    //x = (int) (storable_data.getNumber(0) * scaling_coef + move_x);
    //y = (int) (storable_data.getNumber(1) * scaling_coef + move_y);
    x = storable_data.getNumber(0).intValue();
    y = storable_data.getNumber(1).intValue();
    graphics.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    graphics.drawString(storable_data.toString(), x - 5, y - 5);
}
```

To paint the graph:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    this.graphics = graphics;
    Graphics2D graphics_2d = ((Graphics2D) this.graphics);

    AffineTransform affine_transform = graphics_2d.getTransform();
    affine_transform.scale(getWidth()/(x_max - x_min), getHeight()/(y_max - y_min));
    affine_transform.translate(x_min, y_min);
    graphics_2d.transform(affine_transform);

    for(StorableData storable_data : list_all_points) {
        graphics_2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.drawPoint((Cupple) storable_data);
    }
```

Comment: This is a case where screeshots would be VERY helpful to understand what you are currently seeing and what you would want to see.

Comment: I edited my post, adding a screenshot and the result that I would want to have

Comment: I also added some code

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to translate the points. If you are given a prepared list of them why not draw them directly to the place they need to be at?

Comment: What are `Cupple` and `StorableData`? Consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: I did it (it's my screenshot with the red square), but as you can see, points with Y_1 < Y_2 will be displayed at top of Y_2 and that's not correct

Comment: A `Cupple` and `StorableData` are just data representing a point (so data with two coordinates), that's all. The problem isn't due to these classes. The problem seems to be inherent to `Graphics/Graphics2D` : because its origin is at the top left hand-corner, points are not correctly displayed according to their Y coordinate.

Comment: The coordinate system of components has its origin at the top left, `x` is positive towards the right and `y` is positive towards the bottom. Just negate your `y` value.

Comment: It seems to be very logical in fact, but if I indicate a `-y` for the labels (ie. : `                graphics.drawString(storable_data.toString(), x - 5, -y);`, function `drawPoint`) , the latter disappear : is it normal ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If the rectangles are drawn at the right place then so should the strings.

Comment: If your `y` values are negative then the point will be outside the component's boundaries (above it). You need to move the origin of your coordinate system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you map each data point to a point on the screen, thus avoiding the following coordinate system pitfalls. Take your list of points and create from them a list of points to draw. Take into account that:

- The drawing is pixel-based, so you will want to scale your points (or you would have rectangles 1 to 4 pixels wide...).
- You will need to translate all your points because negative values will be outside the boundaries of the component on which you draw.
- The direction of the `y` axis is reversed in the drawing coordinates.

Once that is done, use the new list of points for the drawing and the initial one for calculations. Here is an example:

```
public class Graph extends JPanel {

    private static int gridSize = 6;
    private static int scale = 100;
    private static int size = gridSize * scale;
    private static int translate = size / 2;
    private static int pointSize = 10;

    List<Point> dataPoints, scaledPoints;

    Graph() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        // points taken from your example
        Point p1 = new Point(-1, -2);
        Point p2 = new Point(-1, 0);
        Point p3 = new Point(1, 0);
        Point p4 = new Point(1, -2);
        dataPoints = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3, p4);

        scaledPoints = dataPoints.stream()
                .map(p -> new Point(p.x * scale + translate, -p.y * scale + translate))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(size, size);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // draw a grid
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            g2d.drawLine(i * scale, 0, i * scale, size);
            g2d.drawLine(0, i * scale, size, i * scale);
        }

        // draw the rectangle
        g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawPolygon(scaledPoints.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.x).toArray(),
                        scaledPoints.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.y).toArray(),
                        scaledPoints.size());

        // draw the points
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        // origin
        g2d.fillRect(translate, translate, pointSize, pointSize);
        g2d.drawString("(0, 0)", translate, translate);
        // data
        for (int i = 0; i < dataPoints.size(); i++) {
            Point sp = scaledPoints.get(i);
            Point dp = dataPoints.get(i);
            g2d.fillRect(sp.x, sp.y, pointSize, pointSize);
            g2d.drawString("(" + dp.x + ", " + dp.y + ")", sp.x, sp.y);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new Graph());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

And another:
[image]

You might want to have the points aligned on the grid intersections and not below and to the right of them. I trust you will figure this one out.

Also, I ordered the points so that `drawPolygon` will paint the lines in the correct order. If your points are arbitrarily arranged, look for ways to find the outline. If you want lines between all points like in your example, iterate over all combinations of them with `drawLine`.